# Selecting rows from a table based on condition of individual columns

Tags: filtering

I'm trying to select all rows from a data set based on a condition off of columns within the data set itself. Broadly what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
SELECT * FROM DataSet[[1;;,All]] WHERE DataSet[[1;;,col1]]-DataSet[[1;;,col2]] < condition
```

In Mathematica, I tried `Select[DataSet[[1;;,All]],DataSet[[1;;,1]]]-DataSet[[1;;,2] < condition]` but I guess the problem is that the `Select[...]` function doesn't tag the condition back to the original data set.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

EDIT:

I have now tried `Select[DataSet[[1;;,All]],Abs[#[[1]]-#[[2]]]<condition&]` is this a valid approach?

Comment: Does your dataset have no headers?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not provide a dataset, I have to emulate one by creating an array `A`:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}];
col1 = 2;
col2 = 3;
condition = 0.5;
```

Using `Select`, you might call

```
Select[A, X \[Function] X[[col1]] - X[[col2]] < condition]
```

This might be a bit more efficient (by almost two magnitudes):

```
Pick[A, UnitStep[Subtract[A[[All, col1]], A[[All, col2]] + condition]], 0];
```